# Failed to install error: Invalid Bundle - No Apple Watch Binary

Tags: ios, app-store, apple-watch

Update to iOS App + Apple Watch App works locally, but when downloaded via the App Store, users complain that the Watch App fails to install, with the following screenshot attached.

[image: Failed to install - Apple Watch]

How can this problem be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restart the Apple Watch.

As far as I can tell, this *appears* to be an issue for Apple to resolve.